# Broke my .zshrc file

Tags: shell-script

Using Mac OS 10.15 - In terminal I edited my .zshrc file by adding this line.

```
export PATH= "/bin/zsh"
```

Now I cannot open the .zshrc file with nano.

I cannot use ls command or sudo. See below.

```
Last login: Wed Mar 10 13:50:48 on ttys000
/Users/macuser/.zshrc:export:5: not valid in this context: /bin/zsh
macuser@MACMINI ~ % -zsh
zsh: command not found: -zsh
macuser@MACMINI ~ % sudo nano .zshrc
zsh: command not found: sudo
macuser@MACMINI ~ % ls
zsh: command not found: ls
```

I just want to fix my .zshrc file if possible. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this is one of those things where I can do the following to change to bash script?     "source ~/.bash_profile"

Comment: Re your comment: That does not "change to bash script", it would source the Bash shell's startup file for login shells using your Zsh shell.  This is not what you want to do.  Instead, follow the advice given by Marcus in their answer below.  Also, you don't ever want or need to edit shell startup files using `sudo`.

Comment: Kusalananda, Marcus Müller and Silfrede, Thank you for the help!

I did experiment on my own; a little clunky perhaps. On my MacBook with 2 good accounts I tried editing user files from another account with my own account in terminal. It worked. I don't know if that will work on the machine with the broken .zshrc file. 

However first I will try using the full path to invoke commands and hopefully fix my .zshrc file. I'll report back with results.

Comment: In the general case, when the  .zshrc or .profile, etc. files have been corrupted, what works (most of the time) is to sftp in and rename the file to something else then login and make repairs.  If the file is polluted enough, this won't work and something more subtle is needed.

Comment: @user1683793 Like a root intervention (login as root, rename user's startup file).

Answer (score 3):

You will need to run programs with their full path now; after all, that's what `$PATH` does, it defines the locations to look for programs in.

So, `/usr/bin/nano ~/.zshrc` (hopefully! I don't know where exactly that lies on your machine!) and remove that line.

It's not quite clear what you meant with `export PATH= "/bin/zsh"`; it is both syntactically incorrect (with the space after the `=`) and content-wise *wrong* (as you notice :) ). You might want to ask a new question about how to achieve what you meant to achieve when you did that!

Comment: Can't see how running `bash` would help unless `~/.bashrc` happens to contain a valid definition for `$PATH`, but `~/.bashrc` is not the right place to do so. An empty `$PATH` means looking for commands in the current working directory only in any shell. Doing `unset PATH` may be more useful. That gives you a *default* search path which may vary from shell to shell.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I agree, I rolled back Wildcard's edit that introduced that

Answer (score -1):

Problem Solved!
This line allowed me to open the .zshrc file:

```
/usr/bin/nano ~/.zshrc
```

However I did not have permission to save changes. I didn't know how to invoke sudo in this situation. I thought about trying to change the permissions [chmod] but I did not do that.

I fixed the file by creating another user and navigated to the file in the affected user account that way. I was able to fix the .zshrc file and all is well. Thank you everyone for your help!!!

Comment: Please edit the question with new details instead of posting an answer containing the already existing answer (in this case, by @Marcus Müller).